# How to wrap background color for some widgets?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-relativelayout, android-view

I want add background for a group of widgets

First I tried to use View, the app will crash

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFC3D7">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="&lt;"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="title"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
</View>
```

Then I tried RelativeLayout, it is work, but it cannot wrap the content

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFC3D7">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="&lt;"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="title"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What is correct way to add background color for widgets?

Comment: Use wrap_content for textviews.

Comment: What do you mean by 'wrap the content'? Does each TextView need to have a background only behind the actual text, or does the background need to extend through the width of the screen?

Comment: background need to extend through the width of the screen, now I fixed the problem by using wrap_content for textviews. But I still have a question, why I cannot use View in the xml? When and how to use the View?